# Multiple groupings of info on an event

Tags: civievent

It's hard to explain it in a headline, but here is what I am trying to do:

We're trying to move our event process fully into CiviCRM instead of doing part of it in Drupal. I know how to add fields to an event, which takes care of like 75% of our need to add fields. But we run into one problem - we need a group of fields that you can use over and over. That would be the details on the hotel. Typically events have at least a few hotels, up to about 5. In Drupal we can just tell the form that we need to utilize a set of fields multiple times; however, as far as I can see you can only do this with fields for Individuals in CiviCRM.

Hopefully I explained this well enough that you can get what I mean. Looking forward to a way to be able to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably make 'Hotels' a contact subtype for Organization, and add a repeating custom group to Event with a custom field of the type 'contact reference'? Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I will go and check that out. I think I know what you're talking about, but will have to go in there and make sure.

Answer (score 0):

In Civicrm you have an option of creating profile which is a collection of fields. For more reference http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/organising-your-data/profiles/

While Event creation you can find an option called online registration just Enable it and you can find Registration Screen where you have an option of adding multiple profile

Comment: That doesn't apply to what I am trying to do. These aren't fields the user fills out, these are fields the person creating the event in CiviCRM will need to fill out. We need to be able to have the location of the event, description of the event, additional info for the event (like special parking instructions), and the recommended hotels. Sometimes there are just a couple, sometimes as many as 5. I need to have fields for things like price, occupancy, name of hotel, web site for hotel, etc. Then all this info shows on the Event Info page for the event.